# MY add to cart button not save user preferred size with it in django no javascript is used

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I want to fetch user selected size with the quantity and product but I don't understand how to do that any how idea to achieve that i try to look documentation but didn't find one any idea how to do that

my views.py for add to cart

```
class Product_detail(View):
    def get(self, request, item_id,):
        item = Item.objects.filter(id=item_id)
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        items = Item.objects.all()
        print(item)
        return render (request, 'product_detail.html',{"items" : item, 'category_list': category_list, 'item': items })

    def post(self, request, item_id):
        item = request.POST.get('item')
        size = request.POST.get('Size')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if cart:
            cart[item] = 1
        else:
            cart = {}
            cart[item] = 1
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        print(request.session['cart'])
        return redirect('products:detail', item_id=item_id)
```

my html code

```
<form method="POST" action="#{{ item.id }}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="text" value="{{item.id}}" hidden name="item">
                  <div class="prefer">
                  <label for="Size" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight:500;">Select Size:</label>
                  <select name="Size" id="size">
                    <option value="S">S</option>
                    <option value="M">M</option>
                    <option value="L">L</option>
                    <option value="XL">XL</option>
                    <option value="2XL">2XL</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary add" type="submit" style="float: left;">Add To Cart</button>
                </form>
```

right now I am only able to fetch its item id and quantity
and look like this {'1': 1} instead i want it t be {'Id': 'Size' : 'Quantity'} all i want to know how to assign a size if a user choose any size basically i want to request size in cart to with its id an an quantity

any suggestion will be appreciated

thank you

previously used code

```
def post(self, request, item_id):
        item = request.POST.get('item')
        size = request.POST.get('Size')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if cart:
            quantity = cart.get(item)
            if quantity:
                cart[item] = quantity+1
            else:
                cart[item] = 1
        else:
            cart = {}
            cart[item] = 1
        request.session['cart'] = cart
        print(request.session['cart'])
        return redirect('products:detail', item_id=item_id)
```

Comment: you are assigning `cart` to session which you have made like this `cart[item] = 1`, the change you have to made here instead of assigning 1 you need to assign size which is variable which has the value of size from post `cart[item] = size`.

Comment: @Chandan but there is problem after that when a user change the size value instead of changing value in the dict new dict will got created but right now it change the values in same dictionary

Comment: {'1': 'M'} , {'1': 'L'} like this not in the same and keep change size value

Comment: instead of creating `cart` dict directly add the value to session `request.session[item] = size`

Comment: @Chandan can you elaborate

Comment: @Chandan because previously using this code for increasing quantity every time add to cart click then made few changes

Comment: test for the type of session object and what are its keys and also check type type of cart after getting from session object.

Comment: do you want to keep both the user size selection or just the latest selection size.

Comment: before I used item.id as key and quantity as a value but after that I changed my change code and make id as a key and size as a value all i asking you is if a user change the size calue of that product again after clicking add to cart instead of   making changes in same list add new one with its the ame id but different size

Comment: {'1': 'M'} , {'1': 'L'} like this same id but two diferrent list instead of keep changing it's size in same list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235618/discussion-between-shreyash-and-chandan).

Comment: @Chandan any problem

Comment: @Chandan yes i want to keep both the user size selection

Comment: than store `cart` as list and add new selection too that `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for every item you are assigning 1 in cart `cart[item] = 1` here we needs size which you are getting from post `cart[item] = size`
- if you want to store each item separately even though user has selected the same item twice then you need to change the cart to list
- for maintaining quantity `{'1': 'M'} , {'1': 'L'}` or `{'id' , 'size', 'quantity'}` structure would not work

```py
# structure
{
  product_id: {
    product_size: product_quantity
  }
}

# example
{
  1: {
    'L': 1,
    'M': 2,
  }
}
```

```py
def post(self, request, item_id):
  item = request.POST.get('item')
  size = request.POST.get('Size')
  cart = request.session.get('cart', None)
  if cart == None:
    cart = {}
  cart_item = cart.get(item, None)
  if cart_item == None:
    cart[item] = {
      size: 1,
    }
  elif cart_item.get(size, None) == None:
    cart[item][size] = 1
  else:
    cart[item][size] += 1
  request.session['cart'] = cart
  print(request.session['cart'])
  return redirect('products:detail', item_id=item_id)
```

Comment: yes i want the cart code  into list format so i can call that in my cart.html please

Comment: All i asking is how to save all three value in the list where quantity can be change by clicking again and agian on add to cart button which is submit button also

Comment: like this {'id' , 'size', 'quantity'}

Comment: @Shreyash I have redesigned the structure, please look if it works for you.